# Flatlist not rendering in react native app

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, debugging, expo

```
const Popularjobs = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const { data, error, isLoading } = useFetch("search", {
    query: "React developer",
    num_pages: "1",
  });

  console.log("Console log from popular job");
  return (
    <View style={styles.cardsContainer}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Popular Jobs</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.headerBtn}>Show All</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.cardsContainer}>
        {isLoading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator size={"large"} color={COLORS.primary} />
        ) : error ? (
          <Text>Something went wrong</Text>
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <PopularJobCard item={item} />}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item?.job_id}
            contentContainerStyle={{ columnGap: SIZES.medium }}
            horizontal
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Popularjobs;
```

Is it the bug of new react-native version?

The FlatList is not rendering at all when i pass the data fetched from api but it does get render when i use dummy data my react native version is 0.73

Comment: try logging the data to see what you are getting if any `console.log('this is what we are getting :'+data)`